# Identify value of <xsl:value-of> context item/node

Tags: java, sql, xml, xslt, xpath

Newbie question on XML and XPath.  I'm debugging some reports produced using an XML transformation, in addition to some associated java and sql functions.  Can someone please help me identify how the following value is populated when the associated xslt is applied to the source XML.

I have the following statement in an xslt:

```
<xsl:if test="$prodType = 'IRS' or $prodType = 'ZCS' or $prodType = 'BASIS'">
  <xsl:value-of select="$root/ISDA"/>
</xsl:if>
```

The $root variable is defined at the top of the xslt as:

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/*"/>
```

So, I would expect that I could find an "ISDA" element in the source XML, but that is not the case.  I see that we're populating a related variable in our java code (which is what shows up in the report I'm sure), but I'm not able to make the connection between the "ISDA" item in the xslt and the "isda" variable in our java code.

Questions:

1. Is there an Xpath function I'm missing?
2. How can the xslt transformation pick up the "isda" value from java (or possibly SQL)?
3. Shouldn't the "ISDA" item/variable be defined somewhere?  I'm unable
   to locate it (I've searched properties files and associated unix
   start-up scripts, but not SQL code which I don't have access to).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

The source XML would start with something like:

```
<SWAP>
 <TradeId>467262IC</TradeId>
 <TradeType>SWAP</TradeType>
 <Env TYPE="EntList" SINGLE="Y">
  <ENV>
  ...
```

Thanks much,

Al D.

Comment: Hi What is the value assigned for '$prodType' . Can you please post you complete XSLT

Comment: Hello Sivaa, thanks for responding. The $prodType variable is defined in the xslt as: `<xsl:variable name="prodType" 

select="$root/Env/ENV/ProductType"/>` The value populated from the XML source in this case is: `<ProductType>IRS</ProductType>`

Hope this helps. I hesitate to share the entire xslt since I'm a contractor and want to limit what I share from the client's code.

Comment: What is expected out ?

Comment: When you say "populating" a variable ... is it with XML or is it just some value? Maybe you have things wrong and should just be passing in "ISDA" as a parameter (not a variable off of root, especially if it is not in your XML)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Sivaa, don't know if this helps, but the actual value was "MXN-TIIE", which does not show up in my XML source document.  Kevin, I agree, I think the ISDA value is being passed in, but I cannot figure out how...looking for clues on the XML/Xpath side of the equation as to how the ISDA value is assigned.  Hope I'm using the correct language here... :^)

Comment: @Kevin, I also did review the Parameter element in the XSLT v2 spec and it does look like a good method to use here.  Not sure why the current approach was taken, but I'm trying to decipher results after the fact. :^)

Comment: Hello All. Here is some info I found from O'Reilly's Oracle XML App ref book (http://oreilly.com/catalog/orxmlapp/chapter/ch07.html): `The input to an XSLT transformation must be a tree of source nodes produced by either parsing a well-formed XML document or creating the tree programmatically (for example, via DOM or SAX APIs).` So, I'm on the right track, cause I see references to these APIs in our java code. Just gotta figure out how to trace these back to my XSLT...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the java method used to populate the variable above.  There are several transformations executed in sequence by the java method, only one of which uses the xslt and XML source file I commented on above.  There is an XML reference source (hiding in a different folder) used in another transformation that held the value I was interested in.

Thanks much,

Al D.

Interestingly, there was no call to the other method I mentioned above that held the similar isda variable, which looks like a little bloat.  Made the search a little tougher :^)